# Custom listview divider line drawn twice on the last item

Tags: android, layout, navigation-drawer

I have a weird issue. My custom listview's divider line (which is actually a linear layout set to 1dp in height on the bottom of the item layout) is drawn twice the height on last items (before headers or at the end of the navigation drawer).

This is how it looks

[image]

This is my listview item layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listItem">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_drawer_bg"
            android:id="@+id/itemClickable"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_itemName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/border_bottom_header"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"></LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my listview heading XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listItemHeader">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/itemHeader"
        android:background="@color/darkgray"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/headerText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#ffeaeaea"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_bottom_header"></LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally this is my background xml file (for the divider layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#474747"
        android:centerColor="#5a5a5a"
        android:endColor="#474747"
        />
    <corners
        android:radius="4dp"
        />
    <size
        android:height="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

Can anyone help me out on this one, I'm really puzzled by this and have no idea where to go from here. I appreciate any help.

EDIT: activity_main.xml which contains the listview

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ff1a1a1a"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem. I added 1dp margins on top and bottom of each listview item and decreased the size of the divider to 1dp. It seems that 1dp of the divider line was overlapped by neighbouring listview items and thus the last items appeared bigger because the last item wasn't there to overlap it as well. So, a small change in the layout file considering the margins resolved the issue.